# Firefox - width: 100% not working for list in a list (display: table;)

Tags: html, css, list, firefox, css-tables

I want to do a navigation with list elements formatted as table so the width of all elements is the same but it won't work for Firefox.

HTML:

```
<div id="#navigation">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a>Menu1</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a>Sub1</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub2</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Menu2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS (some properties are missing but only such things as color...):

```
#navigation {
   position: relative;
   height: 25px;
   width: 852px;
}

#navigation>ul {
   width: 850px;
   top: 0px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 1px;
   list-style-type: none;
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

#navigation>ul>li {
   position: relative;
   height: 25px;
   display: table-cell;
}

#navigation>ul>li>ul {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation>ul>li>ul>li {
   /* nothing really happening here */
}
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZrsXv/2/

Everything works fine in Chrome, Safari, IE8 and greater and with some modifications also in IE6 and IE7

[image: Chrome Menu]

But in Firefox I will always get this

[image: FF Menu 1]

I know I'm not the first one having Problems but I have also tried solutions I found on stackoverflow but **if** something is changing this is everything I get

[image: FF Menu 2]

So is there a solution that won't mess everything up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that position: relative; doesn't really work on table cells. I couldn't find a source at the moment but I'm pretty sure I have experienced the same problem before.

So what is happening in Firefox is that the width of #navigation>ul>li>ul is calculated as 100% of #navigation which is the closest ancestor with a position value other than static (default position value).

You can go around the problem by inserting a dummy element with position: relative; (f.ex. a div) inside #navigation>ul>li and then #navigation>ul>li>ul must be changed to #navigation>ul>li>div>ul

Comment: I'm not 100% a fan of this but it will work...again i think firefox is a real disappointment. if no body comes up with a better idea (because i would like to do it without table stuff but this works best for getting every item the same width without weird spaces) till tomorrow i will accept your answer ;)

Comment: I'm dealing with the exact same situation right now, and I don't understand how you got this solution working. When I add the div, the height of the li with `display: table-cell` stretches to enclose the entire div, so the height of the nav gets huge when I hover to open the dropdown. I have to make the div `position: absolute` in order to prevent that from happening, but then the width doesn't fill the table cell because `position: absolute` makes the width shrink-to-fit. Currently I'm setting the width via javascript. :(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to reference already-existing examples of menus built from nested lists.

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/HTML/Building-a-Drop-Down-Menu-with-Nested-HTML-Lists/2/

I'm not really sure why you're using `display: table`, either; it's been a while since I last made a multilevel menu myself, but I never used that display method, and none of the examples I found after a brief search did either.

Comment: i'm using the the display: table combined with table-layout: fixed so every element has the same size even if i add menu-item with a cms any solution for this?

Comment: Use floated list elements with a specified width and let the menu get wider as necessary; alternatively, if you're able to modify the CSS, you can just add your menu items and then set the `li` width to be (menu width)/(number of top-level `li`s).

Comment: You could also check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29 if you don't want to do that by hand (as CSS itself/alone doesn't support such programmatic actions).

Comment: so there is not a really easy way with just changing 2 properties to get this to work? very disappointing that even ie could do this but not firefox...

Comment: Also before I've tried the table solution I tried with (menu width)/(number of top-level lis)px and (100/(number of top-level lis))%, but this always ended in weird line breakings or space at the end of the navigation div

Answer (score 0):

Reading other answers and comments I understand why you're using `display: table` and it could be acceptable...

I tryed different solutions and nothing work for Firefox so, if you are interested in using this method I can suggest to give the fisrst `li` element width to the children `ul` using javascript / jQuery like I did in your **[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrsXv/5/)**

Otherwise I can not help you in a different way... sorry.